# Unsubscribe link that automatically passes email address

Tags: php, email, unsubscribe

I have searched everywhere, so I am beginning to think maybe this isn't possible. My client wants an unsubscribe link they can add to individual emails (that they send out as a cold call follow up). They do not have a database, so the idea is they have a standard link that they don't need to edit that passes the recipient's email to the unsubscribe.php once clicked. This way my client can make this a standard on their emails and the user only has to click it. Is this possible? I'm not a php expert so I was hoping I am missing something very simple.

This is what I have (and sends the email, but just sends "email")
My email link:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/unsubscribe.php?email=$email
```

Unsubscribe.php:

```
 <?php mail("me@mydomain.com","unsubscribe", $email = $_GET['email']); ?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do they know the recipients of the (I'm guessing) newsletter if they don't have the email addresses stored somewhere?

Comment: What your asking is only possible if magic is real. Assuming it's not, the simple answer is to have the user click the link from the email, and then enter their email address into a form on the page to unsubscribe.

Comment: @Sammitch Even if they enter their email address in a field and submit a form, they wouldn't be removed from the list, because there is no list to remove them from.

Comment: @LazarVuckovic touche. OP should really invest in some CRM software.

Comment: I wasn't looking for "magic", this is not my choice as far as CRM software, etc. My client will manually remove them from their list, I am doing this at their request. All I was looking to do was see if I could have the email address populate itself so the user didn't have to fill out a form. I can do that, which sounds like my only route, but thought I'd see if it was possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, the PHP mail function does not provide a facility to `unsubscribe`.

Where does the `email` come from, if not a database? You can `direct` the unsubscribe link to the program that sets the email and unset it in there.